# Replicate update-manager at the terminal

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I would have thought that the graphical `update-manager` could be reproduced from the terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

yet I can run these commands at the terminal and despite seeing lots of things get upgraded then open the gui `update-manager` immediately afterwards and see that it has a list of updates it wants me to apply. Why is this?

For example today `sambda nameserive integration server`, `command line SMB/CIFS clients for Unix`, ......etc are all queued in gui `update-manager` despite minutes before running the three terminal commands above.

What is going on here?

Comment: After 'Update Manager' was started, and reported updates available, were there actually any to download? *This could just be Update Manager not yet knowing that these updates were handled outside the GUI.*

Comment: Yes, there were and I went ahead and downloaded and installed them (it took a few minutes).

Comment: Yes, there were and I went ahead and downloaded and installed them (it took a few minutes).

Comment: Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent methods.

---

*You may be connecting to a server that is slowly receiving updates, or are using a slower Internet connection.*

You may be able to replicate the issue with back-to-back updates, that would prove that the GUI 'Update Manager' is not the issue here.

eg.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this the next time updates are available in gui `update-manager` by then closing gui, running the terminal command twice and seeing if the second time there still appears to be updates available even in the terminal. I will then check the gui manager and see what is there also.